# "create function" syntax error using "max"

Tags: mysql, max, mysql-error-1064, user-defined-functions

I can't understand what causes a syntax error in a user defined function.

This works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(x INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
RETURN x + 1
```

`SELECT func(10)` selects `11`.

However, the following fails (at creation time):

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(x INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
RETURN MAX(x, 1)
```

It complains about `1)` at line 3 (error 1064).

I saw that delimiters can break things for user defined functions, but I'm not using them at all. What's more, [the example in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) (which uses `CONCAT`, also with commas) works just fine.

What's wrong in the failing function syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function used to determine the greatest of its arguments is called [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) - not `MAX()`. The latter is a [group-by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function which I oftentimes mistakenly use first, too...

In short: `GREATEST()` is used to determine the maximum value from a list of its arguments whereas `MAX()` is used to find the maximum (column) value from a result set.